# Terminal freezes in Linux Mint 12

Tags: terminal, linux-mint, visual-artifacts

Since I installed Linux Mint 12, I'm encountering problems in the terminal.

I'm working with two tabs in the terminal.

Sometimes, when I launch a command on the terminal, it's not refreshed, like freezed with some graphical artifacts. I've to switch tabs twice to have the tab refreshed.

I also got issues where only a part of the screen got refreshed. The weird thing is that the terminal itself never freezes. I can always type in, but most of the time when the problem arise I do not see what I type.

For now, it occurred only when two tabs were open, but perhaps this is not the problem.

Does someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Underneath MGSE (the Mint Gnome Shell Extensions), Linux Mint is really just running the GNOME 3 shell. I don't personally have any AMD/ATi devices, but from what I understand the Catalyst drivers can cause some graphical artifacting throughout the GNOME shell.

So, if you happen to be running an AMD/ATi graphics chipset, and you can't find another solution, you could look into using the open source `xf86-video-ati` drivers. Note also that the issue is/was supposed to be fixed in Catalyst 11.9, so if your drivers are newer than that, this might not be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I'm using NVIDIA drivers. Moreover, the terminal is the only application where I got problems.

Comment: I think that issue can cause application-specific glitches (not sure why). In that case, do you have the option of trying another terminal emulator with tab support (other than GNOME) and seeing if the issue persists?